# Type hint returning inner class of bound TypeVar in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to return the inner class in a bound TypeVar. See below for example:

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound="Base")
class Base:
    class BaseInner:
        ...

def ReturnBaseInner(BaseInstance: T) -> T.BaseInner:
    return BaseInstance.BaseInner()
```

In Pylance the -> T.BaseInner shows an error that the T type does not have .BaseInner as a member. Completely fair, but I feel Pylance should understand this is a bound type and do the resolution correctly.

Why do I want this? Below I show how I might override the inner class in derived classes:

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound="Base")
class Base:
    class BaseInner:
        ...

class DerivedBase(Base):
    class BaseInner:
        def ExtendedFunctionality(self):
            ...

def ReturnBaseInner(BaseInstance: T) -> T.BaseInner:
    return BaseInstance.BaseInner()
```

Is there something I am missing here to make this work? I need to be able to access the extended functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe do something like this to have the help of a function inside the class as well? Ive also used Type to try and get around PyLance

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar("T", bound="Base")

class Base:
    class BaseInner:
        ...

    def get_inner_class(self) -> Type['T.BaseInner']:
        return type(self).BaseInner

class DerivedBase(Base):
    class BaseInner:
        def extended_functionality(self):
            ...

def ReturnBaseInner(base_instance: T) -> Type['T.BaseInner']:
    InnerClass = base_instance.get_inner_class()
    return InnerClass()
```

Comment: I'm still getting a "member BaseInner is unknown" error. Otherwise that is a great suggestion.

Comment: Hmm, is that on the get_inner_class line? Maybe changing the return type to just Type[T]?

Comment: Not sure it will work. I do still need the autocomplete to show ExtendedFunctionality as an option. Type will not allow that as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I settled on this. I hate it but it works.

This passes the type we expect to get back so we can get correct type info.

```
from typing import Type,TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="Base")
class Base:
    class BaseInner:
        ...

class DerivedBase(Base):
    class BaseInner:
        def ExtendedFunctionality(self):
            ...

def ReturnBaseInner(BaseInstance: T, InnerType: Type[T]) -> T:
    return BaseInstance.BaseInner()
```